# VSS - Solution file between multiple users

Tags: path, visual-sourcesafe, projects-and-solutions

we have a solution with multiple projects that is being developed by a team of developers. Project paths in the solution file checked in initially contains the path that are specific to that developer. Now when another dev gets latest of the solution, some of the projects won't load as the path differs.

What's a better way to manage this ?

TIA

Comment: Yeah, stop using VSS and use a reliable source control system.

Comment: LOL, i wish so :) but jokes aside, solution please ?

Comment: How is this a VSS issue?  It is a problem with how they configure the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using VSS, I usually have each developer use a local copy of the solution that isn't kept in source control.

The downside is you have to create a new solution from scratch (or use a template from someone else) for each developer that comes on board, but it does address the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to dictate where projects/solutions are stored, for example, ensure/insist that everyone stores their working directories rooted at C:\VSS. That ensures that all paths are consistent between developers and stops things breaking.